# Как разделить склеенные слова в слове?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, строки, список, re

Проштудировал уже всю библиотеку `re`, но фантазии все равно не хватает.

Есть сотни таких списков:

```
list = ['Фрикадельки', 'овощамиИнгредиентыБаклажан', 'Кабачок', 
        'Стебель', 'сельдерея', 'Болгарский', 'перец']
```

И некоторые слова там склеены. Примерно как `'овощамиИнгредиентыБаклажан'`

Нужно как-то разделить эти слова. Не могу понять за что зацепится здесь.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно так:

```
In [71]: re.split(r"([А-ЯЁ][а-яё]*)", 'овощамиИнгредиентыБаклажан')
Out[71]: ['овощами', 'Ингредиенты', '', 'Баклажан', '']
```

После этого можно еще раз пройтись по списку и удалить пустые строки...

Comment: Не силен в питоне, но вроде так должно сработать без пустых значений в списке `re.findall(r"(?:^[А-ЯЁ]?|\B[А-ЯЁ])[а-я]*", 'овощамиИнгредиентыБаклажан')`

Comment: @PotroNik, да, так тоже будет работать

Comment: конкретно для этой задачи подходит, но аббревиатуры тоже разделяет, тут уже проверочку на капс добавить надо)